# Using react hooks in conjunction with redux-saga (or any other middleware)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

This question was already asked here before, however I didn't find yet any proper answer, just wonder if I missed anything or if indeed this is currently not possible.

Specifically, there are 2 main differences between hooks & redux-saga (or any other middleware):

1. in redux-saga I can trigger code execution on action dispatch, while in hooks I can trigger code execution only on state change. These 2 are not always equivalent
2. hooks must exist in context of component, however some "background" logic (such as initialization, location detection, etc), is not related to a specific component. In redux-saga I have the flexibility to define it in "global scope", while in hooks I must attach it to some "random" component (probably App or any other high level component).

So, is it possible to "bridge" somehow between these 2 approaches, or should I simply pick the most appropriate technique for each specific case ?

Answer (score 3):

They are different tools to solve different problems. Hooks work internally to a functional component's state and lifecycle. Redux works internally to an entire react app's state and lifecycle. Sagas help wrangle asynchronous effects like external data fetches.

Generally speaking you want to limit the scope of variables and logic as much as possible. If a specific piece of "state" is *only* relevant to a single component, then keep it in component state. But if several components or the application itself needs it, then store it in app state. Same applies for asynchronous calls. If a single external call is used by only one component, keep it there, but if multiple components can make the same external async calls, then let the sagas handle them.

You are free to use as much, or as little, as is necessary of either in each component to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, this makes sense to me. I understand that hooks can be used locally by components to track changes in redux's state. I guess my real question was if I can "generalized" them somehow, and use them to handle also some generic app logic, with or without usage of saga, but as I understand this is not possible and I should use redux-saga for this purpose.

Comment: @Tamir You can totally create your own custom hooks to share logic used by multiple components. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html Again, though, these hooks would each only function within a functional component, but can work with redux/sagas.

Comment: I'm aware of custom hooks and already use them extensively, however they still don't allow me to trigger code NOT in component context, and in response to action vs. state change, as redux-saga allows me

Answer (score 0):

1. In Redux-saga you can execute code only on action dispatch. Hooks are more generic, for example with the `useReducer` hook you can trigger code on action dispatch, with `useEffect` you can trigger code on mount/update/unmount etc.
2. Redux-saga also exist in context of a component, or more precisely, whole Redux exists in a (usually top-level) store provider component and Redux-saga is only one of its middlewares. So basically if you have some global app logic and put a hook for it in your `App` component, it is not *some random component*, it is the right place to put the logic to.

I've also recently found a simple library https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-saga-reducer that introduces sagas to React's `useReducer`. (I'm still not sure it is a good idea - just because you can doesn't mean you should, for me hooks async functions are usually enough, but it is at least interesting)

Comment: thanks for this info, however both useReducer & use-saga-reducer do NOT use redux, while I'm already using redux and want to keep using it, just wonder if I can attach hooks to redux action as opposed to state change

Comment: you made a good point about redux that is actually also related to a specific component, so it makes sense to use hooks for the same (root) component I guess

Comment: If the question was whether you can call hooks from Redux reducer, then no, you can't, but that even wouldn't make sense since hooks are designed to put state and lifecycle logic to function components. If you need any logic in Redux, implement it in Redux, then you can Redux actions from hooks via useDispatch. If you feel you need to call a hook from Redux, it is more likely a consequence of bad design - maybe update your question with a specific example when you'd need that approach.

Comment: While its true sagas respond to actions being fired, they don't actually need to respond to the contents of the action. You can write sagas that run when any action is fired anywhere, but then compare previous and current state to decide if code should be executed.